# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xagg.wrappers'

Tags: python

I am trying to import a package 'xagg' but it gives me the error described below. I managed to install 'xagg' but the following error popped up when I try to import it

Here is the command line

```
import xagg as xa
```

The error I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <module>
----> 1 import xagg as xa

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\xagg\__init__.py:5, in <module>
      1 # Eventually restrict to just pixel_overlaps and aggregate; with 
      2 # everything else happening behind the scenes (and the exporting 
      3 # happening as methods to the classes that are exported from those
      4 # two functions)
----> 5 from .wrappers import pixel_overlaps
      6 from .aux import (normalize,fix_ds,get_bnds,subset_find)
      7 from .core import aggregate

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xagg.wrappers'
```

OS: Windows

Comment: how did "managed to install 'xagg'"?

Comment: Hi @emmanuel , could you let me know which version of `xagg` you have installed? `xagg.wrappers` is a module within `xagg`, and so should be loaded automatically with the program. This suggests that this may be an issue with the `__init__` function.

Comment: I also know that people have had issues installing `xagg` on windows (e.g. [here](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg/pull/22))

Answer (score 1):

pip install wrapper

I hope it work

Comment: this will not work in this instance, since `wrappers` is a module of `xagg`, not a separate package